# Python - Password Validation program

Tags: python, while-loop, passwords

I am trying to make a program that carries out password validation when a user is making an account for this first time and has to enter a new password.

The password has to be more than 8 letters, contain an upper case letter, a lower case letter and a number.

I've done the following code, and it doesn't work at the moment. I think it's because `islower()` only works if all characters in the string are lower, same with isupper but for uppercase letters. How can I solve this issue, to get a nice clean solution for the requirements? Thanks

```
while loop:
    pass1 = input('type a password: ')
    if len(pass1) > 8 and pass1.islower() and pass1.isupper() and pass1.isdigit():
        print('password successful')
        break
    else:
        print('Password not valid, please retry')
```

Comment: `.islower()` checks if _all_ characters are in the upper case. Surely, `.isupper()` and `.islower()` cannot be true at the same time.

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming, that is what I thought the issue is, still not sure how to get around this problem though.

Comment: make a loop like ```for c in pass1:```. This will iterate over the whole pw while ```c``` is the current  character in every iteration. There you can user ```isupper/islower/isdigit``` and store in a variable what you observed.

Answer (score 0):

Create another if else statement where you check islower method return true or false or set it equal to another boolean value then use that value in the second(which is your main if statement) statement then run it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
def anyLower(s):
    return s.upper() != s

def anyUpper(s):
    return s.lower() != s

def anyDigit(s):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in s)

while True:
    userInput = input("Type a password: ")
    if len(userInput) > 8 and anyLower(userInput) and anyUpper(userInput) and anyDigit(userInput):
        print("Password successful")
        break
    else:
        print("Password not valid, please retry")
```

anyLower() function converts the string to uppercase and checks if it changes, if it has changed, then the string must contain at least one lowercase character. anyUpper() works in a similar way.

anyDigit() iterates through all of the characters in the string and returns true if any of the characters are digits using the any() function.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, and seems to be working for me. I'm a new learner, so will have to look over this a bit more to understand it, thanks for this solution though.

Comment: Do not use `str` as a variable name: it is a built-in string constructor.

Comment: @DYZ I have changed the name to `s` instead

Comment: I would have preferred a more descriptive name myself :-) In any case, it's not really necessary to make multiple passes over the string.

Answer (score 0):

The condition that you are looking for is as follows: the password must be alphanumeric, but it must *not* consist of all lower-case letters,  it must *not* consist of all upper-case letters,  it must *not* consist of all letters, and it must *not* consist of all digits:

```
pass1.isalnum() and not pass1.isupper()\
                and not pass1.islower()\
                and not pass1.isalpha()\
                and not pass1.isdigit()
```

Comment: Nothing states the whole password must be alphanumeric, the requirements seem to allow for `aB3_and_something_else`. Additionally, your expression will allow too-short passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can try utilizing the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) method along with the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method to check if any of the characters in the string, mapped with your choice of `str` method, returns `True`:

```
conditions = str.islower, str.isupper, str.isdigit
while True:
    pass1 = input('type a password: ')
    if len(pass1) > 8 and all(any(map(c, pass1)) for c in conditions):
        print('password successful')
        break
    else:
        print('Password not valid, please retry')
```

Answer (score 0):

> The password has to be more than 8 letters, contain an upper case letter, a lower case letter and a number.

It's good programming practice to code to functional requirements so it would be useful to have a specific function such as `is_password_valid()`.

And, since the intent is to check if all the conditions are met, you can exit early before needing to check all the characters (possibly many times) as some of the other answers here do. In other words, something like (with a test harness):

```py
import sys

def is_password_valid(password):
    if len(password) <= 8:
        return False

    has_upper, has_lower, has_digit = False, False, False

    for character in password:
        if character.islower():   has_lower = True
        elif character.isupper(): has_upper = True
        elif character.isdigit(): has_digit = True

        if has_lower and has_upper and has_digit:
            return True

    return False

chs = ['1', 'a', 'B', '_']
for ch1 in chs:
    for ch2 in chs:
        for ch3 in chs:
            for ch4 in chs:
                str1 = ch1 + ch2 + ch3 + ch4 + "....."
                print(f"{str1} : {is_password_valid(str1)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you have with the code (assuming that I understand the purpose of the program) is how you put these length, type and format check.
My take on your program - @BarCode - is that you want the user to input a password that is more than 8 letters, contains both uppercase and lowercase letters as well as numbers.
If this is correct then what you want to do is use the following if statements:
`if pass1.isalnum()` - so if it contains numbers and letter
`if pass1.isupper() or pass1.islower():` - to see if all the characters are upper or lower.
To check the length of the password you need to create a variable - `length = len(pass1)`. Then set an if statement - `if length > 8:`
So the end result would look like this:

```
loop = False
while loop == False:
  pass1 = input('type a password: ')
  length = len(pass1)
  if length > 8 :
    if pass1.isalnum():
      if pass1.isupper() or pass1.islower():
        print("Password invalid ")
      else:
        print('password successful')
        loop = True
    else:
      print('Password not valid, please retry')
  else:
      print('Password not valid')
```

This is a more simple way to do it compared to the other suggestions however, so I'd understand if it is not up to your choice.